# Find discontinuities of the function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, functions, continuity

My function is $y= \sqrt{(1-\cos(πx))/(4-x^2)}$.

The main question I have problems with answering is wherever  2 and -2 are removable discontinuities and why.

Should I think about the domain of my function? Are limits where $ x\to 2^{+}$ and $x\to -2^{-}$ non-existent? Because by the definition of the one-sided limit the dots should belong to the function’s domain if I understand everything correctly. And, if so, does it mean that only limits where $x\to 2^{-}$ and $x\to -2^{+}$ exist, and does it mean that based on these statements I can conclude that limits where $x\to 2$ and $x\to -2$ exist, so these discontinuities are removable?

Comment: Have you tried plotting the function?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can see that this function contains points (2, 0) and (-2, 0), but I want to understand the limits part and how the domain affects the process.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $(-2,2)$, right? With this, the limit when $x\to -2^-$ or $x\to 2^+$ no make sense. Don't exist values $x<-2$ or $x>2$ in the domain

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you mean by "removable discontinuity," and note that definitions you have encountered may not be well-defined in all circumstances.

Comment: My definition of the removable discontinuity is correctness of equality: $f(x_{0}-0)=f(x_{0}+0)$, but the thing is, that in both situations(with 2 and -2) I can only get one part of the equation, because the other one is non-existent, but I can clearly see on my graph that I have (2,0) and (-2,0), which leads me to the thought of removability.